# React Native dev server does not run on device

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native v0.35 after upgrading from v0.26. I can no longer use the dev server on my device like I used to. When it builds to my phone, connected on the same wireless ip as my macbook, it builds from a pre bundle instead of the server. I used to be able to just set the ip in the app delegate, but that's no longer an option. I just want to be able to develop on an actual device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is seeking a solution to this problem:

The issue was that if you are developing on ios using a macbook, the code that governs the auto ip detection fails to pick up your machine's ip, so it defaults to the pre bundled package. In order to resolve this (for versions >= 0.29 && < 0.36-rc.1 - which already includes this patch), open up your node modules directory, find the react-native directory, then open that and find the packager directory. In packager, there is a file named 'react-native-xcode.sh', open that up. Then, find the code snippet and add the three lines of new code from [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/8adf78ffc9b0e66cfb00227f53c25d47a5a5fcbd). After that, rebuild your app and restart your packager. The dev server should now load.

Comment: Hey there, I'm using RN 0.38 and still having this issue. I've checked the `react-native-xcode.sh` and the lines you've highlighted are already there. Still, running my project from my MBP to my iOS phone always results in pre-bundled. Any idea? Cheers!

Comment: Assuming that you're building for dev and not production, its likely that your phone and macbook are on different wifi networks (maybe one is on wifi-1 while the other is on wifi-2, subtle but different). If you're convinced that they are, in fact, on the same network, then I would register a bug on the react native github issues page and downgrade to a version that works for you in order to develop. Best.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm building for dev, of course, and my phone and macbook are on the same network. Changing the IP in webSocketExecutor.m to my IP triggers the tab opening of localhost:8081/debugger-ui, so we can assume the connexion is working. I'll try downgrading to 0.37 to see what happens, if nothing works, I'll open up a bug report. Best

Answer (score 0):

You can try few things -

- Make sure you have set debug server host and port on device.
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html
- Restart server
  `npm start`
  or
  `npm start -- --reset-cache`
- Re-install app (delete and install)